# how to select wipe data/factory reset in iball andi 4p class x V-8 in recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, locked-out

i also have this problem in my android phone iBall Andi 4P class-X my android version is 4.4.2 kitkat. I successfully get into recovery made there i can move the highlight with the help of volume keys but i cant select the 'wipe data /factory reset' option. i have forgotten my pattern for one week and my phone is laying down, please help me to solve my problem that how can i select the factory reset option with which key? for further information:- in the recovery mode there is written the full name of my phone like this- "iBall.Andi.4P.Class-X_V8.0,2015-7-31" please solve my problem as soon as possible . THANK YOU

Comment: Have you tried the power button to select the menu? That's how it usually works.

Comment: yeah i hve tried it but the phone doesn't give any response

Answer (score 0):

Hey go to recovery mode again and to proceed further u need to click home button and the button which is on ur lefthand side that is the option button next to  home button .. Press those button all at once